# Getting 'KeyError: destination' when making redirection to oAuth provider using redirect_to_auth_server()

Tags: python, flask, openid-connect, flask-oidc

**I would like a way to activate and deactivate OIDC checks using [flask-oidc](https://flask-oidc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).**
Using the `@require_login` decorator is a problem as it cannot be deactivated. For instance :

```
g_use_oidc = True # <= A global boolean to activate or deactivate OIDC at application level

@app.route('/') # <= Flask routing
@require_login # <= Flask-OIDC making redirection to oAuth provider
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

This is working well with OIDC as I get redirected to my oAUth provider. But now I want `g_use_oidc` to be set to False and `@require_login` to stop redirecting calls.

---

In order to achieve this I created a decorator to check the `g_use_oidc` status like the following :

```
def check_oidc_test(func):

    @wraps()
    def inner():
        if not use_oidc or oidc.user_loggedin == True:
            func()
        elif use_oidc and oidc.user_loggedin == False:
            return oidc.redirect_to_auth_server(None, request.values) # <= Redirection to OIDC provider as shown in the doc
    return inner
```

I should be able to use the decorator like this :

```
@app.route('/')
@check_oidc # <= my new decorator
def home():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Unfortunatly I get this stacktrace from OIDC :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "x.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2088, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "x.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2073, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "x.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2070, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "x.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1515, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "x.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1513, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "x.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1499, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**req.view_args)
  File "x.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_oidc/__init__.py", line 657, in _oidc_callback
    plainreturn, data = self._process_callback('destination')
  File "x.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask_oidc/__init__.py", line 707, in _process_callback
    response = self.extra_data_serializer.loads(state[statefield])
KeyError: 'destination'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

I looked at the code of `@require_login` which looks like this :

```
if g.oidc_id_token is None:
    return self.redirect_to_auth_server(request.url)
```

([require_login_code](https://github.com/puiterwijk/flask-oidc/blob/7f16e27b926fc12953d6b2ae78a9b9cc9b8d1769/flask_oidc/__init__.py#L480))

So I wasn't far...

I updated my decorator to match theirs

```
def check_oidc(view_func):
    @wraps(view_func)
    def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
        if g_use_oidc is True and oidc.user_loggedin == False:
            return oidc.redirect_to_auth_server(request.url)
        return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
    return decorated
```

It's using `oidc.redirect_to_auth_server` which is deprecated as of 1.0.0. But it's the function that is being used internaly in `@require_login` so it's not thaaaaat deprecated.